# App Store download/installation status?

Tags: ios-appstore

Does the AppStore not provide download / installation status?

[image]

I clicked on get app, and all I see is "installing". No status, no feedback, nothing. Is this normal? I know Xcode is a big download, so I know it will take a while, but feedback would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Check Download Progress on the Mac App Store](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/27/check-download-progress-mac-app-store/):

> **How to See Download Progress of Apps Coming from the Mac App Store**
>
> Want a general idea of an app downloads progress? Here’s what to do:
>
> - From the Mac App Store, click on the “Purchases” tab to see the active list
> - Locate the app(s) you are downloading that you want to check

Also if **Launchpad** is in your **Dock** it typically shows some information too.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use launchpad.